# Issues using regular expression match in the IF statement in powershell

Tags: powershell

Input File content is at the bottom. The image shows better the file format.

As you can see from my input file it comes with lots of lines that I don´t need, so I´m trying to tell Powershell to read the content when line matches this pattern (see below). But it´s returning False and not doing what I´d like which is to copy all the content between the regex and the - sign which indicates where the block ends.

Any idea of what I´m doing wrong?[image]

```
$InputFile = gc "D:\input_file.txt"
$Dest = "D:\Desktop\Final_file.txt"

#PATTERN I´M LOOKING FOR:
 0000 00XKDPMBBRAXXX00000
 1965 81PWSLKDTRUGXX00000

#REGEX I´VE CREATED BASED ON ABOVE CONTENT
$re = [regex]'(\d{4}\s\d{2}\[a-z]{12}\d{5})'

$file_line_num = 0
$mesg_line_num = 0
$Dest_count     = 0

foreach ($line in $Input_File) {
  $file_line_num = $file_line_num + 1

  # Find where message starts, any other lines are ignored
  if ($line -match $re) {

     [void]$foreach.MoveNext() # skip lines not needed

     $msg_line_num = 0

     do {
        [void]$foreach.MoveNext()    
        $line = $foreach.current
        $msg_line_num = $msg_line_num + 1

        if ($msg_line_num -lt 3) {

           $header = $line.substring(7,8) + $line.substring(16, 3)
           add-content $Dest $header

        } else {
           add-content $Dest $line
        }

     } until ($line -eq "-" -or $line -eq $null) 
  }
}
Exit
```

---

```
text
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEXTHERE TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE
.TEXTHERE TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
0000 00XKDPMBBRAXXX00000
1965 81PWSLKDTRUGXX00000
123 99
TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE//TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE//TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE//TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
-
=TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
=TEXTHERE TEXTHERE



NNNN++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                                      +
+     -- =TEXTHERE TEXTHERE            +
+      =TEXTHERE TEXTHERE              +
+                                      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

TEXTHERE TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE
.TEXTHERE TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
0000 00XKDPMBBRAXXX00000
1965 81PWSLKDTRUGXX00000
123 99
TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE//TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE//TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE//TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
-
=TEXTHERE TEXTHERE
=TEXTHERE TEXTHERE



NNNN++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                                      +
+     -- =TEXTHERE TEXTHERE            +
+      =TEXTHERE TEXTHERE              +
+                                      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Nor from code neither from text can I see what the desired output should look like, simply filter the lines matching the pattern to the output file?

Comment: Thanks for editing, don´t know how to do that. the output should show the content starting from the regex pattern till it finds the - (dash) sign, for all blocks of content within the file.

Comment: Comments are meant for that, only for that. Edit your question to contain the additional information. As you see it's illegible. And your question didn't tell anything about more information to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\[a-z]` should be `[A-Z]` - the slash is not needed because it produces a literal `[`, also `[regex]` class is case-sensitive unlike the usual `-match` operator.

Anyway, it's possible to shorten the code (PowerShell 3.0 and newer):

```
$all = ([regex]'(?s)(?<=(\d{4}\s\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{12}\d{5}\r?\n){2})(.*?)(?=\r?\n-\r?\n)').
    Matches((Get-Content source.txt -raw)).Value
```

Or PowerShell 2.0:

```
$all = ([regex]'(?s)(?<=(\d{4}\s\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{12}\d{5}\r?\n){2})(.*?)(?=\r?\n-\r?\n)').
    Matches([IO.File]::ReadAllText('r:\source.txt')) | Select -expand Value
```

To copy including the boundary lines too change the groups in the regexp:

`'(?s)(?:\d{4}\s\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{12}\d{5}\r?\n){2}.*?\r?\n-\r?\n'`

Comment: My version is 4.0 so I tried the first approach but it´s suppressing the regex pattern and the - in the output. My output desire would be to include the regex pattern until it finds the dash sign - (which indicates the end of the block) then continue looking for the next regex pattern until the -

Comment: Your question states `copy all the content between the regex and the - sign` which is what the answer does. Anyway, modifying the regexp to your needs is trivial, I've added an example in the answer since the comments here break copypasting of code.

Comment: Yeah, you´re right and I apologize for not being so clear before. I have to spend more time studying regex, do you have any good place from where I could learn and practice it more?

Comment: http://regexstorm.net/tester is for C# and PowerShell regexps, https://regex101.com/ is one of the most helpful generic regexp testers and of course there are many tutorials.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check it out for sure. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
> select-string .\input_file.txt -Pattern '(\d{4})\s(\d{2}[a-z]{12}\d{5})'

input_file.txt:8:0000 00XKDPMBBRAXXX00000
input_file.txt:9:1965 81PWSLKDTRUGXX00000
input_file.txt:38:0000 00XKDPMBBRAXXX00000
input_file.txt:39:1965 81PWSLKDTRUGXX00000
```

---

```
> select-string .\input_file.txt -Pattern '(\d{4})\s(\d{2}[a-z]{12}\d{5})'|%{$_.matches.captures.value}
0000 00XKDPMBBRAXXX00000
1965 81PWSLKDTRUGXX00000
0000 00XKDPMBBRAXXX00000
1965 81PWSLKDTRUGXX00000
```

---

```
> select-string .\input_file.txt -Pattern '(\d{4})\s(\d{2}[a-z]{12}\d{5})'|%{$_.matches.groups[1,2].value}
0000
00XKDPMBBRAXXX00000
1965
81PWSLKDTRUGXX00000
0000
00XKDPMBBRAXXX00000
1965
81PWSLKDTRUGXX00000
```

Comment: Thanks @LotPings, I´ll try to use the second example to grab the pattern and think of something else to fill out the block content with the text until it finds the - sign.